# Deleting default category in wordpress

Tags: categories, customization

I'm looking for a way to delete default category functionality in wordpress but after i delete the default category in `wp_terms` table in mysql database, it automatically assigns default category to another category.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible. WordPress *requires* a default category, that’s hard coded.

If you need a taxonomy without default value – create a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. No wonder i couldn't find that information in google. Actually i was using `wp_insert_post` to insert my post, the new post was always assigned to both default category and my intended category. I have added `mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '1'");` to delete the `term_taxonomy` in `wp_term_relationships` table, so now i have resolve my problem without actually having to removing the default category feature of wordpress.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `wp_remove_object_terms($post_id, 1, 'category');` to remove the default category.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

This is a very old question but I had a similar requirement and I found a way to do it.

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_default_category', '__return_empty_string', 999 );
```

### Why the above code will work?

This will give empty string to WordPress when it's trying to set default category on post save here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7004afe4f4bac1fd17a142051832bdf6be8e6fcf/wp-includes/post.php#L3672-L3680

```
// Make sure we set a valid category.
if ( empty( $post_category ) || 0 == count( $post_category ) || ! is_array( $post_category ) ) {
    // 'post' requires at least one category.
    if ( 'post' == $post_type && 'auto-draft' != $post_status ) {
        $post_category = array( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
    } else {
        $post_category = array();
    }
}
```

Later it will try to assign that category here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7004afe4f4bac1fd17a142051832bdf6be8e6fcf/wp-includes/post.php#L3955-L3957

```
    if ( is_object_in_taxonomy( $post_type, 'category' ) ) {
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_category );
    }
```

and that function will return true from elseif since category array is not empty but value is empty in here https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7004afe4f4bac1fd17a142051832bdf6be8e6fcf/wp-includes/post.php#L4613-L4622

```
if ( empty( $post_categories ) ) {
    if ( 'post' == $post_type && 'auto-draft' != $post_status ) {
        $post_categories = array( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
        $append          = false;
    } else {
        $post_categories = array();
    }
} elseif ( 1 == count( $post_categories ) && '' == reset( $post_categories ) ) {
    return true;
}
```

Note, user will see option to set default category in `wp-admin/options-writing.php` this code does not disable that but that functionality won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by manually removing the record in the database, if I recall correctly it was located in wp_terms but I could be wrong.

Comment: yes, you can always delete the default category in `wp_terms`, but after it is deleted, WP automatically assign the default category to another existing category

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is to go to your table 'wp_options' and set 'default_category' to 0.

I can't understand why people keep saying that a term is an absolute requirement of Wordpress. It's not.

Answer (score -1):

If nothing else, you can change the default category from "uncatogorized" to "news" or something relevant for your use.